# How can I add an image header to my php mail form?

Tags: php, email

So I have a standardized mail form that has certain generated details that must accompany it including a header image.
I am trying to find out how to add the image to the text form for when I send it.
I have

```
$img_path = 'image12.jpg';  //declaration

  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

{ 
    echo "<tr>";  

    $emailContent=str_replace("\\r\\n","",$row["generic_email_text"]);   
    echo 'Test';
    echo '<td width="450"><textarea name="genericemail">'.$img_path .$emailContent.'</textarea></td>'; 
    echo "</tr>";
}
echo "</tr>";   
echo "</table><p>";
```

I tried adding img_path to it but it won't work. I'm taking over from someone elses code which I always find difficult. All I get with this is the name of the img ("image12")

And yes I havnt done PHP in a while

Here's the PHP for pulling the form info

```
$fullName = $firstName . " " . $lastName;
    $imageFile = str_replace = '<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';  //Header here is just a place holder
    $updatedEmailText = str_replace("%name%", fieldHtmlFormat($firstName), $updatedEmailText);
    $updatedEmailText = str_replace("%firstname%", fieldHtmlFormat($firstName), $updatedEmailText);
    $updatedEmailText = str_replace("%lastname%", fieldHtmlFormat($lastName), $updatedEmailText);
    $updatedEmailText = str_replace("%duration%", fieldHtmlFormat($durationOfStay), $updatedEmailText);
    $updatedEmailText = str_replace("%destination%", fieldHtmlFormat($arrivalCity), $updatedEmailText); 
    $updatedEmailText = str_replace("%travel%", fieldHtmlFormat($travel), $updatedEmailText);   
    return $updatedEmailText;   .
```

edit:
  changed code:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
    { 
        echo "<tr>";  

        $emailContent=str_replace("\\r\\n","",$row["generic_email_text"]);   
        echo 'Test';
 //LINE 50'<td width="450"><textarea name="genericemail"><imgsrc="'.$img_path.'"/>'.$emailContent.'</textarea></td>'    }//LINE50
    echo "</tr>";   
    echo "</table><p>";
```

Comment: what is in `$img_path`? Some html? Or just a server-side path like `/path/to/images/kittens.jpg`? You can't put html into a textarea like that and expect it to be rendered. and since this is going out as an email, you can't use external images anyways, since external resources are NOT loaded automatically by pretty much every mail client on the planet. You need to build a proper MIME email, and EMBED your images.

Comment: Hello, Yes It's a fully automated email and the image is on the server. Thanks for pointing me in the direction of MIME. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `<img>` tag in order to show the photo.

Replace the line:

```
echo '<td width="450"><textarea name="genericemail">'.$img_path .$emailContent.'</textarea></td>';
```

With this line:

```
echo '<td width="450"><textarea name="genericemail"><img src="'.$img_path.'"/>'.$emailContent.'</textarea></td>';
```

And also make sure that you have the correct file/url path for `$img_path`.

Comment: Thanks for your help although I'm getting a small error saying Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in  (link to code) on line 50

Comment: I left the bit eddited at the end for you. I can't post much more of my code unfortunately.

Comment: Looks like you are missing a semi-colon (;) right after ```</td>'``` on line 50.